# Hebrew in Html email body is not readable

Tags: c#, encoding

I am trying to parse an Gmail's email. I am using Imap methods and so far so good.
My problem is with html emails. I searched everywhere for converting html body to plain text but nothing works for me so I am trying to do it myself. I am taking the html, clearing the all the attributes and now I have an encoding issue.
Some of my emails are in Hebrew and the Hebrew in the html looks like this :

> =F0=E0 =F6=F8=E5 =E0=E9=FA=E9 =F7=F9=F8 =E1=E1=F7=F9=E4 =E1=E8=EC=F4=
>   =E5=EF
>
> I tried converting it from hex to string but the result wasn't perfect. some words were missing.

How can I convert is to Hebrew chars?

Thanks a lot,
Elad

Comment: When you display that HTML in a browser, do you see the correct text? Could you show (as edit to your post) a relevant fragment of that HTML?

Comment: Hi, No it is also shows as hex chars. I Uses Blachshma solution and I could see the Hebrew chars. The problem is that the Hebrew words, that are in the same line in Gmail, look like this in the HTML code - <span>=F0=E0 =F6=F8=E5 =E0=E9=FA=E9 =F7=F9=F8 =E1=E1=F7=F9=E4 =E1=E8=EC=F4=
=E5=EF 0526546545<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p>
<span><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p>
<span>=E0=E1=E9</span><span><o:p></o:p></span></p> - they are in separate paragraphs so it is hard to parse them as a full sentence. I hope I make myself clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some encoding issues with the HTML you receive.
You're going to need to convert it to the correct encoding.

This works:

```
        Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
        Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");

        string msys = "=F0=E0 =F6=F8=E5 =E0=E9=FA=E9 =F7=F9=F8 =E1=E1=F7=F9=E4 =E1=E8=EC=F4=E5=EF";
        msys = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(msys.Replace('=', '%').Replace(" ", "%20"), latinEncoding);

        byte[] latinBytes = latinEncoding.GetBytes(msys);
        string hebrewString = hebrewEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);
```

First part of your problem is that the `=F0=E0..` are actually URLEncoded with a `=` instead of a `%` at the begining. So we replace the problematic characters and [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) it.

Afterwards, we convert it from the `Windows-1252` encoding to the `Windows-1255` encoding.

As a side note: there is a problem in the example string you gave: `=F4= =E5=EF` should actually be `=F4 =E5=EF` (the `=` character is always before, not after the decoded part)

I tested it and it works fine on your string... בהצלחה

Comment: Thanks :) Your solution worked. I think I need to find a good "html email to plain text" converter because Outlook html emails are hard to parse if they contain Hebrew chars. If you have any code code examples it would be great. Thanks again!